# Make a multi architecture static library in C

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries, unix-ar

I'm working on Ubuntu and I've made a static c library following the instructions on [this site](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html).

But the resulting .a package works only on the machine where it has been compiled.

I know that an .a archive contains object files (only one in my case), so, can I package together object files compiled in different machines (i386 and amd64) in a way so GCC can know which file should be using?

If I cannot, can at least make my library recognizable by other same-arch machines?
(using `-L. -llibraryname`)

Example:

archive name "libvisualt64.a"

command: `gcc -o main main.c -L. -lvisualt64`

Says:

```
skipping incompatible ./libvisualt.a when searching for -lvisualt64
cannot find -lvisualt64
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In this case I compiled the source and built the archive in the same 64bit machine just yesterday.
And yesterday it worked fine.
This happens on 32bit machines too.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on *how* it doesn't work on other systems using the same architecture? What errors do you get?

Comment: Apple has a dual-architecture system (it was quadruple at one time, when Macs used PPC chips).  Normally, on Linux, you build a 32-but library and a 64-bit library and install them separately and link with them separately.

Comment: In any case, this is only peripherally related to C.  You can build libraries of functions whose source is written in C, but such libraries are not themselves a C thing.

Comment: Use `file` command to inspect the files. Also, use `ar` command to inspect the *.a* archive (read the man page to find out how, probably add `v` for verbose output).

Comment: Why not just ship a bunch of .a files in a directory structure like `.../artemis/$(uname -i)/$(uname -s)/libvisualt64.a"? Selecting the lib path in your build system is much simpler than using an exotic linker format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses an executable file format called [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).
An ELF file can only contain the necessary machine code for a single architecture.

There should be no problems using your library on another machine of the same architecture. The only potential issue could be related to dependencies.

If you *really* want a single binary to support multiple architectures, then you may be interested in [FatELF](http://icculus.org/fatelf/)... Though it is not supported [without a kernel patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary#FatELF:_Universal_Binaries_for_Linux):

> Up to now the FatELF is not integrated in the kernel mainline.

---

To address your edit, it is likely that your `libvisualt64.a` is not built for the same architecture that `gcc` is targeting...

You'll need to extract the object files from the archive, and compare them with `gcc`'s target:

```sh
ar xv ${STATIC_LIBRARY}
file *.o
gcc -v 2>&1 | grep '^Target: '
```

I see the following (compatible) outputs:

```
test.o: ELF 64-bit LSB  relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: You have dependence issue when you import exotic libraries? I think mine are quite standard: stdio.h stdlib.h string.h termios.h unistd.h time.h stdarg.h

Comment: @Artemis These all sound standard enough... please see my edit, and report back.

Comment: I got:
ELF 64-bit LSB  relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Eww.. is this possibile on a 64bit os? So i made two 32bit libraries.. That leaves the fact That neither 32bit versions are recognized by other 32bit machines

Comment: Well there you go! :-) `x86-64` is not compatible with `i686`. Are you definately using the same toolchain between sessions? run: `which gcc` each time, and record it session to session.